# TFS 2010 Source Control Explorer - annoyances coming from VSS

Tags: tfs

I am trying out TFS 2010 Source Control Explorer for managing some non-Visual Studio projects. Having previously used VSS, there are 3things I was expecting to be able to do which I can't:

1.Folder compare doesn't default to mapped local folder

Every time I right-click a server folder and do Compare, it requires me to enter the local folder path to compare to. What a pain! I have mapped the server folder to a local folder, so was expecting it to default to that.

2.Having opened a folder comparison, if I right-click a file that is different on disk, and check it out (intending to keep the local version then check it in) I get the error:

The item C:\inetpub\wwwroot...... could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it.

I am running SCE as Administrator, and the file is not read-only, and is writable with other applications.

Also, there is no option (like in VSS) to not overwrite with latest version, so I fear that if the check-out did work, the above error indicates that SCE would overwrite the local file.

3.In the regular SCE window showing contents of a server folder, the option to Checkout For Edit is greyed out on all files. However, as mentioned above it is available through folder compare.

What am I missing?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the folder is correctly mapped in your workspace? Most of the symptoms sound like you're working with non source-controlled files. Checking out a file will not usually overwrite its contents if it has been made writable (But as with any SC system, take a backup copy first to be on the safe side)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out ....
Until you do a Get Latest/Specific version, none of the above 3 functions work (even if the file exists locally and is identical to the server version). Its like TFS has to know that you did get the file from its repository before it will cooperate!

As soon as you do this (and watch out because when you go the Get, there seems to be no option other than to overwrite the local file, so have a backup copy somewhere if they are different), then the 3 functions work:

- Folder compare defaults to mapped local folder
- Check out/in works from the folder compare window
- Check out/in works from the explorer window

Comment: Exactly so - TFS **does** have to know that you did the get from its repository before it will cooperate.  TFS is very aggressive about storage of the client's state.  This allows it to be very efficient about computing what data the client needs (based on what data it has.)